# Save APK files from Google Play on desktop/laptop

Tags: google-workspace, backup, download

I used to browse Google Play apps through my laptop regularly. Is there any way that I can store the Android applications (`.apk` files) into my laptop? In other words, download the `.apk` file straight to my PC.

I wish to backup my `.apk` files for my personal testing with my Android simulator.

Comment: See: [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12330)

Comment: @AlEverett thanks a lot i forgot to browse that site before posting here

Comment: Your issue with getting apps for the simulator is a separate issue. You'll want to get the Play Store app in your simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Real APK Leecher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1563894) works...so should [apk-downloader](http://codekiem.com/2012/02/24/apk-downloader/)

(but downloading .apk is not recommended...you might instead want to save it to apk through device)

EDIT: steps for Real Apk Leecher

1. use [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evozi.deviceid&hl=en) app to know your device id
2. [Download](https://code.google.com/p/real-apk-leecher/) Real Apk Leecher and enter details it asks for (**it asks for your google account password**, so rather create a new account for this purpose exclusively)
3. start earching and downloading apps

note: though it enlists even the paid apps, it can download only free apps...and you need Java Runtime to run the app...worked about 6 months ago....should still work perfectly...

Comment: i tried real apk leecher the download is very slow,and apk downloader solved my problem thank a lot